# How to remove the error in eclipse juno when using lambda expressions?

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda

I am using eclipse juno for my project. I am trying to do convert from String array to integer array. For this expressions, I am using below code.

```
String[] c1 = {"5","4","2","1"}; int[] c = Arrays.stream(c1).mapToInt( Integer::parseInt()).toArray();
```

how to remove this error in eclipse.
please can any one help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse Juno does not support lambdas (or Java 8 in general). You need to be using Eclipse Mars (or Luna) for full Java 8 support.

Answer (score 1):

change it to

```
int[] c = Arrays.stream(c1).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

no need of round brackets (parenthese) for method references `Integer::parseInt` is enough

Comment: what error are you getting? hope are you using Java 1.8

Comment: It shows that "The method Integer() is undefined for the type" at the place of  Integer::parseInt().   I did without brackets but  it shows error "Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens"

Comment: did you remove the `()` in `parseInt` ?

Comment: int[] c = Arrays.stream(c1).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();  I trying this way .but it not resolved

Comment: String[] c1 = {"5","4","2","1"};

Comment: Set system library to java8 and clean the project once in eclipse